# Dividing strings in python 2.7

Tags: string, python-2.7, math, raspberry-pi, configuration-files

I have been working on a automated blinds/ curtains project for some time now It all works well but I would like to add the function of the Blinds gradually opening in the morning. I am reading my values from a config file and have converted the values into strings which works fine, just can't divide that value for some reason. I have tried many ways of doing this but I seem to come across errors such as- SyntaxError: can't assign to operator and TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects. Has anyone got any idea's on how I can divide a python string then use that string as a sleep value??

I am fairly new to programming (I'm 13)

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
config = SafeConfigParser()

config.read('/home/pi/config.conf') #read config file
openTime = config.get('blinds', 'open time(secs)') # -> "openTime"
print 'Overall open time ' + openTime + ' seconds'

## code to divide openTime by 5 and print the value

print 'gradual open time' + DividedOpenTime + ' seconds'

## code to repeat in a loop 5 times with a sleep of the value of 
## DividedOpenTime
```

**EDIT 1**

Hi again I have done what I was told to add to the code and it has solved the issue of the division and sleep time but for some reason I can't print the values. Both lines 11 and 15 have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print 'gradual open time' + divOpenTime + ' this will repeat 5 times'
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
config = SafeConfigParser()
import time

config.read('/home/pi/config.conf') #read config file
openTime = config.get('blinds', 'open time(secs)') # -> "openTime"
print 'Overall open time ' + openTime + ' seconds'

divOpenTime = float(openTime)/5 #working (:
loop = 0
print 'gradual open time' + divOpenTime + ' this will repeat 5 times'

for x in range(0, 5):
    loop += 1
    print 'gradual opening stage ' + loop + '/5'
    #GPIO true- I know how to do this
    time.sleep(divOpenTime) #working (:
    #GPIO False- I know how to do this
    time.sleep(15) #time between each interval fixed value
```

Thanks Ed

Comment: Errors are the most important part of us helping you. Please post the errors as is here as well. And kudos to you for starting to program at an age when most of us lazy bags were just playing videogames :)

Comment: Thank you, hoping to add more things like relay boards and stuff to my home automation project once I've got this sorted i'll add errors next time    @Ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the string into a number to do computations with it,

```
DividedOpenTime = float(openTime)/5
```

Comment: Has worked in my code but can't print the values for some reason see my Edit on my question. Thanks for your help though because it solved the main issue

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out

```
 print 'Gradual open time ' + str(divOpenTime) + ' seconds this will repeat 5 
 times'
```

you have to add/convert your float value into a string so it can print. You do 
this with:

```
str(Your_float_value_here)
```

Thanks again for all your help Ed

Comment: Or use formatting, `"%8.4f"%divOpenTime` also converts the float into a string with controlled length and number of decimals (it is old style, the string formatting framework has also a modernized version).